# serde_json with deserialize and lifetimes for generic function

Tags: rust

Having issues with lifetimes and serde::deserialize.
Tried reading the error message and tried implementing Deserialize, but then I got an error that I need to implement Deserialize.
Without lifetimes, it works

```
use serde::{ Deserialize, Serialize, de::DeserializeOwned};
use std::error::Error;
use std::io::{BufReader};
use std::{ fmt::Debug};
use std::{fs::File};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct User<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
}

fn main(){
    let b: User = read_object("user_1.json").unwrap();
}


fn read_object<T>(path: &str) -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>
where
    T: DeserializeOwned + Debug,
{
    let f = File::open(&path)?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(f);

    let t: T = serde_json::from_reader(reader)?;

    Ok(t)
}
```

Error:

```
   error: implementation of `Deserialize` is not general enough
  --> src/main.rs:13:19
   |
13 |     let b: User = read_object("user_1.json").unwrap();
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ implementation of `Deserialize` is not general enough
   |
   = note: `User<'_>` must implement `Deserialize<'0>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
   = note: ...but `User<'_>` actually implements `Deserialize<'1>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code cannot work.

The [`Deserialize<'de>`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.127/serde/trait.Deserialize.html) trait has a lifetime associated with it to support *zero-copy deserialization*. Essentially allows deserialized types to reference data directly from the source. See [Understanding deserializer lifetimes](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html).

When you have

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct User<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
}
```

The `User` will have the lifetime `'a` linked to the deserialization source. And `name` will be a reference to the string value within that source.

On the flip-side, the [`DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html) trait does not support zero-copy deserialization. The deserialized type must not have lifetimes associated with the `Deserializer`. The "owned" means it doesn't borrow from anything. The cryptic error you get is due to the way `DeserializeOwned` is defined, it'll be implemented for any type that implements `Deserialize` for *any* lifetime, which will exclude types expecting a particular lifetime. This bound is used when lifetimes are unecessary or impossible to guarantee.

`serde_json::from_reader` is one of those cases. It only deserializes JSON from sources based on the `Read` trait. However, the `Read` trait makes no guarantees that any read data is referenceable after the fact. And thus `from_reader` dictates that `T: DeserializeOwned` to avoid that problem.

To take advantage of zero-copy deserialization, you'd need to use [`from_slice`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.from_slice.html) or [`from_str`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.from_str.html):

```rust
let data = std::fs::read_to_string(path)?;
let user: User = serde_json::from_str(&data)?;
```

However, even if you do that, the data being referenced is local only to the `read_object` function. All data retrieved from the file is destroyed at the end of the function, and would leave `user.name` invalid if it were returned. The compiler would reject it ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0a9a5832b6e7f9f54ff2b676569c45ca)).

> Without lifetimes, it works

And that's what I suggest you do; just use `struct User { name: String }`. I would advise against trying to use zero-cost deserialization from JSON strings at all because of [escape sequences](https://d3lm.medium.com/rust-beware-of-escape-sequences-85ec90e9e243).